# Standard suffixes for compounds?

Tags: nomenclature, terminology, drugs

Long ago, I learned that suffixes like -ide, -ate, -ose, etc. had specific meanings.

Now, I'm seeing all these drug ads on TV with generic names that all end in -ab or -ib.  Do these have a standard meaning, or is it a matter of conforming to the crowd?

Comment: You can add a few examples. This is not a universal ending.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/161667/why-does-almost-every-drug-that-causes-dependence-have-this-ine-suffix

Comment: Note that pharmacological and chemical nomenclature conventions are independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything ending in -ib is a kinase inhibitor e.g. [Dasatinib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dasatinib)

Anything ending in -mab is a monoclonal antibody e.g [Rituximab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rituximab)